# Cannot use environment variable in Circleci orb

Tags: circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am trying to create a Circleci workflow which builds and uploads a java WAR to my organizations existing S3 artifact storage bucket repository. First, the project is built and some information is saved in a file, as well as VERSION being put into BASH_ENV:

```
export "VERSION=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec)" >> $BASH_ENV
  if [ $CIRCLE_BRANCH = "master" ]; then
    ENVIRONMENT=production
  elif [ $CIRCLE_BRANCH = "develop" ]; then
     ENVIRONMENT=qa
  elif [ $CIRCLE_BRANCH = "release-1.0" ]; then
     ENVIRONMENT=staging
  else
     ENVIRONMENT=$CIRCLE_BRANCH
  fi

  echo "ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT" >> project.info
  if [ -z "$ENVIRONMENT" ]; then
    echo No environment is set
  exit 1
    fi
```

Then, I attempt to upload the artifact using the official S3 orb:

```
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - run: source project.info
      - run: export "VERSION=$VERSION" >> $BASH_ENV
      - aws-s3/copy:
          from: target/project-${VERSION}.war
          to: 's3://artifact.bucket/project/project-${VERSION}.war'
          arguments: '--dryrun'
```

This upload task fails with `The user-provided path target/project-.war does not exist.` Because an empty string is being interpolated instead of the expected version.

The Circleci documentation states:

> In every step, CircleCI uses bash to source BASH_ENV. This means that BASH_ENV is automatically loaded and run, allowing you to use interpolation and share environment variables across run steps.

Yet it appears that this is not the case. How do I make the S3 upload tasks use the environment variables I am setting?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment varialbes as pre_build steps

```
      - my-orb/orb-name:
          context: org-global
          pre_build_steps:
            - run:
                name: Set IMAGE_NAME for kustomize
                command: |
                  echo "export IMAGE_NAME=\"connectivity-wiki\"" >> $BASH_ENV
```